# I am trying to protect secret strings in my code, did I do everything right?

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, obfuscation

I wrote this code which encrypts and decrypts strings in AES / CBC because I have been warned that it is safer than using AES / ECB.

```
private static final String IV = "nVj1Vakka8jaVn9d";

private static final String AES_MODE = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
private static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";

public static String encrypt(String message, String password) {
    try {
        byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes(CHARSET);
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(password.getBytes(CHARSET), AES_MODE);
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes(CHARSET));

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_MODE);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(messageBytes);

        return Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

public static String decrypt(String base64EncodedCipherText, String password) {
    try {
        byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.decode(base64EncodedCipherText, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(password.getBytes(CHARSET), AES_MODE);
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes(CHARSET));

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_MODE);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encodedBytes);

        return new String(decryptedBytes, CHARSET);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My application contains secret strings that should not be viewed by decompilers. All these strings are encrypted in String fields by the return of this encrypt method. The IV in theory is not secret then I put it simply as a String field in the class, the password is recovered securely by Firebase whenever necessary and is never saved in SharedPreferences or code.

Did I do everything right?

Comment: Looks like a request for [codereview.se].

Comment: 1. The IV needs to e different random value for each encryption, it is generally made a prefix to the encrypted data. 2. This fails for an attack against the running code where the decryption key is in memory. 3. It is also necessary that the key in memory is overwritten after use, not just released,this can be tricky.

Comment: why not go with hashing instead of encryption and decryption ?

Comment: @user641887 What advantages will I have in using hashing?

Comment: @zaph Sorry, I do not understand 2 and 3.

Comment: 2. The attacker runs your code with a debugger and examines memory at the time you are decrypting the strings. 3. After the key is used it is in memory, the memory will be released, mainly no pointer to it, the key value will remain in memory until some future time the memory is re-used.

Comment: Backing up, what skill level attacker are you trying to protect against and what is the value of the strings? IOW what is the threat model.

Comment: @zaph It is a game about puzzles, the only thing missing for the release is the protection of the levels' answers. Strings are just a few phrases containing the answers, but if someone finds out once, they will spread all the answers on the Internet without solving the puzzle.

Comment: @zaph How can I protect my strings for items 2 and 3?

Comment: Areyoujust comparing the user's answer to these strings? If so you can use a salted and iterated cryptographic hash

Comment: Yes. It is only made a comparison between what the player entered and the response of that level.

Comment: his seems to be a duplicate or extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46780925/strings-protection-in-android-application) you asked, answered and accepted  a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: The question is different

Comment: @zaph Okay, for the comparison of the answers I can use hash. But I also encrypted the strings used in the layout of the levels and decrypt and add the plain text at runtime. What do you suggest for this?

Comment: Probably the best thing you can do is delete this question and create a new question with all the additional information in it. Explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish, this question keep changing with more information added in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a salted and iterated cryptographic hash. The actual answer will never e in the code.

Run the answer through a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions during development and add the result + salt to the code. It is not reversible and resistant to brute force attacks.

In the code take the users answer and run it through the same method with the same salt and compare the results.